# The Sands of Time

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

In the museum at the Roman fort of Vindolanda (Northumberland, England) there is a paving flagstone bearing a dog's pawprints. An itinerant, mischievous dog had the temerity to walk over wet, Roman concrete in the early Second Century.

This reminded me of a verse from Longfellow's "Psalm of Life":

"Lives of great men all remind us

We may make our lives sublime,

And, departing, leave behind us

Footprints in the sands of time;

A possible translation could be:

vitae magnorum omnes nos commonent

vitas sublimes faciamus,

discessuri (retro) reliquerimus

vestigia in harenis temporis;

Two problems: sources (Pock. Ox. Lat.) & Wiktionary give "relinquo" = leave (behind); "behind" in brackets, like it's an optional extra. Therefore (L3), is the inclusion of "retro" necessary?

Secondly, L3: present participle "discedentes" (we are) departing or the future "discessuri", followed by future perfect: "about to depart we will have left behind..."?

Some help, please?

Comment: Nice  thought. I like commoneo. I would have translated faciamus as 'Let us make...' ; You could get round this by using *licet* with the infinitive of *facio* and *disced...* ;but that would possibly involve subordinating the first line -*Ut vitae...*

Comment: @Hugh: Thanks. Yes, the hortative subjunctive "let us" = "may we"; I needed "we may". Perhaps the imperfect subjunctive--"faceremus" = "we might". The imperf. subj. always seems vague, weak & wishy-washy; still, when needs must.

Comment: My own reading of the English is that 'may' is equivalent to Latin licet, as Hugh suggested, not to a hortatory or other type of subjunctive. Lines 2-4 are indirect statement after 'remind, so I'd say something like vitae...commonent licere….

Answer (score 3):

*Relinquere* means “leave,” but not just in the sense of “remove oneself from a place,” but also to “leave behind.” E.g. in his *Bello Gallico*, Caesar [writes](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/caesar/gall1.shtml) (1, 12, 2):

> Caesar certior factus est tres iam partes copiarum Helvetios id flumen traduxisse, quartam vero partem citra flumen Ararim **reliquam** esse …
>
> *Caesar was informed that the Helvetians had already ferried three parts of their people across the river; that, however, the fourth part was **left** on this side of the Arar river …*

This is what the bracketed addition in the dictionary is trying to express. But this is a metaphorical “behind,” the idea being that we turn our backs on the things or people that we “leave behind.” When we say that we leave footprints behind us in the sand, the “behind” is quite literal, and the verb *relinquere* does not deliver it.

That does not mean you have to render it in Latin, though. After all, where else are you going to leave footprints? Sometimes, especially in poems, words are just there for the sound or the rhythm. If you are going to render it, I feel *post nos* would be a more natural choice than *retro*, which usually describes a direction of a motion.

The English text implies that the *relinquere* happens at the same time as the *discedere*, so I would say *discedentes* is the right form, corresponding directly to the English.

Also, I would prefer *reddere* to *facere*, but I suppose this is a matter of taste.

Lastly, I agree with the comments that the English *may* is not hortative, because it depends on *remind*. So this ends up becoming:

> … commonent ut liceat nobis sublimes nostras vitas reddere et, discedentes, vestigia relinquere …

**Edit:** As cnread said in his comment, *commonere ut*  typically carries the meaning of suggesting or urging an action, which one would translate as *to* + infinitive in English, e.g.: *commonuerunt ut caveremus* = “they reminded us **to** be careful.” This is not what I intended here; rather, this *ut* introduces an indirect interrogative clause, literally “they remind us **how** it is granted to us …” – this in order to avoid a double a.c.i.

Looking this up, I just noticed even my short pocket grammar explicitly mentions this case: *monere* + a.c.i. = remind; *monere* + final clause = admonish. In light of this, it is perhaps better to say:

> … commonent nobis licere sublimes nostras vitas reddere …

Comment: To clarify: you're using the *ut* in your translation as an interrogative adverb, right? (So a translation back into English would be '...remind *how* it's permitted to us...'?) This may be worth pointing out in your answer, because I think many people who see (*com*)*monent* + *ut* + subjunctive will tend to try to construe it as indirect command (e.g., '...remind that it should be/is to be permitted to us...') instead of indirect question. I heartily approve of your choice of reddere instead of facere; that's a nice touch.

Comment: @cnread Ugh, you are right, _commonere ut_ certainly typically introduces a final clause with a meaning of admonishment (commonishment?) – although the _liceat_ would not really make sense in that case.